# how to lift the data with regex in python that's between two semicolons?

Tags: python, regex

I got a set of lines in a file that's separated by semicolons like this:

```
8=FIX.4.2;9=159;35=A;56=MBT;34=1;7202=asdf:asdf;52=20130624-04:10:00.843;43=Y;98=0;10=000;Timestamp=Fri July 25 1958 16:12:52:112545;MsgDirection=1;
```

What I want is the whole message up until 10=000; and the value of 7202 which would be asdf:asdf.

I got this:

```
(^.*000;)
```

which according to regex should get me the whole line until 10=000;. Which is great. But if I do this:

```
(^.*000;)(7202=.*;)
```

according to the regex101.com means I won't match anything.

I don't know why adding that 2nd grouping invalidates the whole expression.

any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Regexes don't nest like that. You want something like this `^.+7200=(.+;).+=000` now the entire match is the string up to `10=000` and the capture group is `asdf:asdf;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer for first version of question

*"I am trying to use regex with python to lift out my data from 7202=, so I want to get the asdf:asdf."*

If I understand correctly, your goal is to find the data that is between `7202=` and `;`.  In that case:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "8=FIX.4.2;9=159;35=A;56=MBT;34=1;7202=asdf:asdf;52=20130624-04:10:00.843;43=Y;98=0;10=000;Timestamp=Fri July 25 1958 16:12:52:112545;MsgDirection=1;"
>>> re.search('7202=([^;]*);', line).group(1)
'asdf:asdf'
```

The regex is `7202=([^;]*);`.  This matches:

1. The literal string `7202=`
2. Any characters that follow up to but excluding the firs semicolon:
   `([^;]*)`.  Because this is in parentheses, it is captured as group 1.
3. The literal character `;`

#### Answer for second version of question

*"What I want is the whole message up until 10=000; and the value of 7202 which would be asdf:asdf."*

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "8=FIX.4.2;9=159;35=A;56=MBT;34=1;7202=asdf:asdf;52=20130624-04:10:00.843;43=Y;98=0;10=000;Timestamp=Fri July 25 1958 16:12:52:112545;MsgDirection=1;"
>>> r = re.search('.*7202=([^;]*);.*10=000;', line)
>>> r.group(0), r.group(1)
('8=FIX.4.2;9=159;35=A;56=MBT;34=1;7202=asdf:asdf;52=20130624-04:10:00.843;43=Y;98=0;10=000;', 'asdf:asdf')
```

The regex is `.*7202=([^;]*);.*10=000;`.  This matches:

1. Anything up to and including `7202=`: `.*7202=`
2. Any characters that follow up to but excluding the firs semicolon: `([^;]*)`. Because this is in parentheses, it is captured as group 1.
3. Any characters that follow starting with `;` and ending with `10=000;`: `;.*10=000;`

The value of the whole match string is available as `r.group(0)`.  The value of group 1 is available as `r.group(1)`.  Thus the single match object `r` lets us get both strings.

Comment: Think OP also wants the part of the string up to `10=000`

Comment: @JaredSmith I was keying on this text from the question: _"I am trying to use regex with python to lift out my data from 7202=, so I want to get the asdf:asdf."_.  I'll agree with you that it is possible that he is looking for something else.

Comment: @John1024 Sorry, I didn't phrase the question very well, indeed I am trying to get both information.